# Is there a Google Chrome Extension archive anymore?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

There used to be a couple of websites that archived Chrome extensions because Google does not provide a way to download old versions of extensions.

However, those sites appear to longer be maintained.

Is there any Google Chrome archive site still working?

Comment: Have you tried `https://www.crx4chrome.com/`?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Yes, the newest version of the extension I was looking for was 2015, so I think they are not collecting extensions anymore, or at least not all of them.

Comment: What extension is that? Your question only mentions "Is there any Google Chrome site still working"?

Answer (score 7):

[Crx4Chrome](https://www.crx4chrome.com/) is still active and functional. When you are on an extension page, it shows up to 10 old versions. To view more older versions click on "More Version History".

[image: IMG:]

To each page shows 10 versions. Go at the bottom of the page, to navigate between the different versions when there are more.

[image: IMG:]

In the example of ublock origin, the oldest version on the site is 1.9.10 while the latest at the time of this writting is 1.27.10. See images below.

[image: IMG:]
           [image: IMG:]

**Note:** Although the oldest version was on page 6, it is not listing versions on that page from 51 to 60 but still 1 to 10.

**Disclaimer:** I used ublock Origin as an example of an extension I used whose versions are listed on the [site](https://www.crx4chrome.com/). I am just a user of the extension, not related to the developer(s).